# Add completion for deleteRowAtIndexPaths with an extension or didEndDisplayingCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'd like to do something after `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` has finished it's animation.

I can achieve this by wrapping it in `animateWithDuration` but it doesn't feel like the right way of doing it.

Another way is using `didEndDisplayingCell` but I can't update the section here or else it will get in an infinite loop.

What I'm trying to do is:

- Delete a cell by swiping it
- Remove it from my data model
- Delete the row with `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`

After the row has been deleted and animation has ended:

- Reload sections by calling `reloadSections`

The code I'm using:

```
func deleteObject(ojbectName: String) {
    let indexPath = // create indexPath

    // Delete the item in data model and table
    myData.removeAtIndex(index)
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Left)

    // Reload section after row animation has ended        
    let indexSet = NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: NSMakeRange(myData[indexPath.section].startIndex, myData[indexPath.section].endIndex))
    tableView.reloadSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: .None)
}
```

I tried creating an extension for `UITableView` that didn't go well. Is there someone who can tell me how to create one or how to use `didEndDisplayingCell` so I can reload the section after the animation has ended?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing `didTransitionToState` in your subclassed `UITableViewCell`. Check out [the Apple docs on this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/didTransitionToState:)

`